# CRA 5 upgraded to Webpack 5. How does it help using Webpack Module Federation with CRA without ejecting?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-module-federation, cra

Module Federation requires Webpack 5.
The new Create React App (CRA) v5 released last December was upgraded to Webpack 5.
How does it help using Webpack Module Federation with CRA without ejecting?
Any guide on how to do it in a clear way?

Answer (score 0):

this is has been done already .
You can find the full example in module-federation-examples repo

https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/cra